# Multiple Scraping with Scrapy spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I wanted to scrape a [website](https://www.cato.org/research/34/commentary). The extraction I want to do is, document list, author name, and date. I watched some scrapy spider videos and able to figure out 3 shell script command which gives the required data from the website. The commands are

```
scrapy shell https://www.cato.org/research/34/commentary
```

for date:

```
 response.css('span.date-display-single::text').extract()
```

for author:

```
response.css('p.text-sans::text').extract()
```

for the Document links in the page

```
response.css('p.text-large.experts-more-h > a::text').extract()
```

I am trying to get it through Python but all in vain. Since there is multiple data.

Here is the python code:

```
import scrapy
class CatoSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'cato'

    allowed_domains = ['cato.org']

    start_urls = ['https://www.cato.org/research/34/commentary']


def parse(self, response):

     pass
```

Comment: Don't use `css` for this, better is `xpath`

Comment: I'm trying to build one more module and the task will be to click article link and extract date, author, and article title. And do this for all article link the webpage (cato.org/research/34/commentary). Please help

Answer (score 0):

This should work. All that you need is just run this command:
`scrapy runspider cato.py -o out.json`
But as I can see, there is mistake with links, you will take only text from links, not href

```
import scrapy

class CatoItem(scrapy.Item):
    date = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    links = scrapy.Field()


class CatoSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'cato'

    allowed_domains = ['cato.org']

    start_urls = ['https://www.cato.org/research/34/commentary']


    def parse(self, response):
        date = response.css('span.date-display-single::text').extract()
        author = response.css('p.text-sans::text').extract()
        links = response.css('p.text-large.experts-more-h > a::text').extract()
        for d, a, l in zip(date, author, links):
            item = CatoItem()
            item['date'] = d
            item['author'] = a
            item['links'] = l
            yield item
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I can't say how thankful I am. Just need to ask one thing that "Catoitem" class separate or it has to be used with that 2nd spider part?

Comment: You can put `CatoItem` in the same module that your spider, but it is bad practice, better is put it in `items.py` because you can have many spiders in the future and it will be easy to import it from one module.

Comment: You are a life saver.

Comment: I am getting a couple of error in running.It What I did is, I made a python and put class catoItem above and below the second part from import Scrapy. And ran this python file with command scrapy runspider "filename.py" and getting NameError: name 'scrapy' is not defined. What could have possibly gone wrong?

Comment: you don't need put `CatoItem` above and below import Scrapy, only before definition your spider class. Are you installed Scrapy? try to run so: `scrapy crawl cato`

Comment: I am using anaconda. I think I have scrapy installed properly. Please tell how should I run it. What I tried next is I saved I  named catoitem class item.py to the location. And second by scrapy.py . And ran the command scrapy runspider scrapy.py. Is it the right way.

Comment: I managed to run it.But I can't see the required output in the Anaconda console. Once I saw in the video they took the output in json file. Can I get the output in notepad?

Comment: Try it: `scrapy runspider scrapy.py -o out.json`

Comment: And then how to open JSON file? Is there a way to get the output in notepad?

Comment: Yes, notepad should open `.json`, but I'd recommended using some editor like sublime or msvs code

Comment: Is there command any to open JSON file from shell or I  have to go to the location and open it from there.?

Comment: Sir, I just checked JSON file. It's empty can you please check this once at your end.It is very much important for me.

Comment: you are great help. But I think it's not extracting. I am able to make json file and check the output but it's blank. Please Please have a look.

Comment: I can't tell you how thankful I am. I literally struggled with this.Please don't get me wrong, if next time I need your help can I reach you through your email. If yes, Please just say a "Hi" to hayatt.143@gmail.com. Thanks Again.

Comment: I'm trying to build one more module and the task will be to click article link and extract date, author, and article title. And do this for all article link the webpage (https://www.cato.org/research/34/commentary). Please help.

Comment: you shouldn't make one more module. Just make request again

Comment: How I do it. We already have the template code. Can you please modify it accordingly? @marni

Comment: Please help me with.